# # in part of the field name, Access thinks it is a date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writing a VBA that if the Parcel# matches Me.Parcel to make the font bold on the button. # is part of the field name. MS Access thinks it's a date. This is my code. It keep getting "syntax error in date in query expression". I know it has to be something simple i am missing.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If DCount("*", "County Address Table", "Parcel#'='" & Me.Parcel) Then
        Me.[COUNTY ADDRESS HISTORY].FontBold = True
     Else
        Me.[COUNTY ADDRESS HISTORY].FontBold = False
    End If
```

Comment: Try `"[Parcel#] = '" & Me.Parcel & "'"`. And better not to use special characters in field names anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Table and column names *can* have special characters, but then they need to be quoted in queries, lest things go south - like a `#` character being interpreted as a `Date` literal delimiter =)

In fact, quoting field names should be the default way to do things, for various reasons.

Use `[` square brackets `]` to quote identifiers, [as already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232878/in-part-of-the-field-name-access-thinks-it-is-a-date#comment117096928_66232878):

```
If DCount("*", "[County Address Table]", "[Parcel#]'='" & Me.Parcel) Then
```

Consider avoiding spaces and special characters in new table and new column names: `CountryAddressTable`, `ParcelNumber`, etc. are easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

"First part of string" & Chr(35) & " second part of string"

Comment: That fixed it. It's an older database and would take a lot of work to remove the characters. Thank you

Comment: @dulster note that it's also obscuring the actual name of the object, which isn't making future maintenance any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me.[COUNTY ADDRESS HISTORY].FontBold = _
        Not IsNull(DLookup("[Parcel#]", "[County Address Table]", "[Parcel#] = '" & Me.Parcel & "'"))

End Sub
```

If Parcel# is a number, remove the single-quotes.